# Function call using previous value?

Tags: javascript

```js
// The global variable
var bookList = ["The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"];

// Change code below this line
function add (bookName, test) {
  console.log('t', bookName)
  let newB = bookName;
  newB.push(test)
  return newB;
  // Change code above this line
}

// Change code below this line
function remove (bookName) {
  var book_index = bookList.indexOf(bookName);
  if (book_index >= 0) {

    bookName.splice(book_index, 1);
    return bookName;

    // Change code above this line
    }
}

var newBookList = add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time');
var newerBookList = remove(bookList, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');
var newestBookList = remove(add(bookList, 'A Brief History of Time'), 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');

console.log(newBookList, newerBookList, newestBookList)

console.log(bookList);
```

`t [ "The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae" ] t [ "The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae", "A Brief History of Time"`

How come there is the two strings; "A Brief History of Time" and "A Brief

History of Time" is it saving the value and using it again? How would it

remember that there was a brief history in time in the last function call?

The function call in the third global variable is add(bookList, 'A Brief

History of Time') so what is happening?

If you don't understand what I am saying, basically, I am trying to fix the

add() function and it's working but it's run twice because it's assigned to

two variables and the problem is that in the newestBookList, the add()

function added the string, but it added the string to the array that I made

before in the add() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way you have named your variable in the line: `let newB = bookName;`, this line of code is not doing what you think it's doing. It is not creating a new instance of `bookName`, it is just assigning to `newB` the existing array reference passed in on the `bookName` parameter, which is `bookList`.

Since you continue to pass in `bookList` and do not get a new array reference with something like `[...bookName]` or `bookName.slice()`, it keeps using that same array with each subsequent call. So it will continue to push values onto the same array. That's why you're getting the output you're getting.

One example of how you can return a new array reference each time is like so:

```
function add (bookName, test) {
  console.log('t', bookName)
  let newB = bookName.slice(); // generates a new array with the same elements
  newB.push(test)
  return newB;
}
```

Comment: @StudentUser1625 Spread syntax relies on specific browser support - if you want to be safe, just use `.slice()`. It does the same thing in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you reassign your array in the `add` function your just passing on the array reference. This causes the original array to be

If you intent to use your bookList as an initial state and `add` and `remove` to change and return the new state. Another problem I see in your code is that on your `remove` you are also changing the original array with the `splice` function. If you intent to follow this approach I recommend the following changes to make sure you're not overriding the original state.

```js
// The global variable
const initialBookList = ["The Hound of the Baskervilles", "On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies", "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "Disquisitiones Arithmeticae"];


function add(prev, bookName) {
  return [...prev, bookName];
}

function remove(prev, bookName) {
  const idx = prev.indexOf(bookName);
  if (idx === -1) return [...prev];

  return [
    ...prev.slice(0, idx),
    ...prev.slice(idx + 1, prev.length),
  ];
}

const bookList1 = add(initialBookList, 'A Brief History of Time');
const bookList2 = remove(initialBookList, 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');
var bookList3 = remove(add(initialBookList, 'A Brief History of Time'), 'On The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies');

console.log({
  initialBookList,
  bookList1,
  bookList2,
  bookList3,
})
```